# bootstrap 4: Button with Icon and text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create buttons like you can see below with Bootstrap 4:

[image]

The icon (font awesome) should be centered to the text and all the icons have the same y position on the screen. The border of the buttons should be invisible.

Do I have to use a button or is it better to use another element? Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With Bootstrap 4 and Font-Awesome, if you want to place the icon to the left of the text, use the following snippet

```
<button class="btn btn-lg" style="background-color:transparent;">
   <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit
</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

Create a `div` and then put  font-awesome icons into it and then write text then provide necessary `css` and then you can use `(click)` event on the `div`.

```
Install bootstrap and font-awesome
```

and then provide the path in the   'styles' of angular-cli.json.
            or,

```
<button class='btn btn-lg ' style='background-color:transparent;'> 
  <div style='text-align:center;'><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>  
    Cancel Reservation
</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try out this. It will solve your query.
`<a href="#" class="btn btn-success"> <i class="flaticon2-pie-chart"></i> Success </a>`